# Inline-block using more than total width

Tags: html, css

So I've working on a Game Concept for a while and I've been trying to create a website based around the game as some heavy practice. So far so good, but now I'm at a bit of an issue (it's not project hindering, but it would make everything look nicer if I could figure out a solution!)

So to start off, the problem is fairly simple. I'm trying to get two elements side by side, they currently look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/helzs.png).

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<p class="stat-text"><strong>Strength:</strong></p> <p class="stats">500</p>
```

CSS:

```
.stat-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.stats {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My problem is that the "Strength" and the "500" are too far away from each other. I'd like to make them closer, but I'm unsure how. I've tried "margin" which had no effect. I've tried "float" but it makes the background disappear and negates the inline-block for me. I've also tried things like "left" and so forth, but nothing has given me the desired outcome.

I've looked up this problem but nothing seemed to have worked, can anyone give me some advice on how to shrink the distance between them? (preferably keep the "Strength" where it is but bring the "500" closer)

Comment: Inline block elements kind of act like text. Remove the space between them in the HTML. You might also have styling on <p> tags elsewhere that is giving them more styles than you think.

Comment: where is background

Comment: Using just your code above results in the text being pretty close already.  Do you have other markup that could be affecting the spacing?  Like images in the `<p>` tags that you have omitted in your post above?  or a surrounding `<div>` with extra styling?  "select element" in your browser dev-tools (f12) should help you track down the culprit and even fiddle with the margins and padding until you are happy.

Comment: make both of text in a single para graph

Comment: @JimCote Thank you, however that didn't work to the fullest extent. I'll experiment around, though.

Comment: `.stats { transform: translateX(-10px); }` where `10px` is the distance you want it to move.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you so much! I didn't even know that was a thing xD. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @reyder no problem. I'll add it as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move something around relative to where it is currently using `translate()`. To move `.stats` to the left `10px`, use `.stats { transform: translateX(-10px); }`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p class="stat-text"><strong>Strength:</strong>500</p>
```